# Parsley.js localization in Angular2

Tags: angular, parsley.js

I'm unable to make Parsley.js messages localized in hebrew language.

I load the following scripts in my vendor.ts file

require('./node_modules/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js');
require('./node_modules/parsleyjs/dist/i18n/he.js');

And in the component.ts:

```
window.ParsleyValidator.setLocale('he');
jQuery('.parsleyjs').parsley();
```

The error message I'm currenlty getting is:

**he is not available in the catalog(…)**

Appreciate your help.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the locale, you should read the error/warning messages in the console, which would inform you that and you should *not* be calling `ParsleyValidator.setLocale`. You should always specify which version you are using. You should provide a working example.

Comment: The version is 2.5.1.

Comment: When I do not call setLocale, there are no error messages in the console, but the validation texts are still in english.

Comment: Right. That's because the `i1n/he.js` isn't loaded. Not sure why though, double check how things are required and what's the resulting javascript file.